Using React to write into Json file
So im trying to create a small cafe website using react. customer told me that he wanted his orders to be be visible on admin dashboard, so i thought i would make something like this:
import React from 'react';
import { OrderType } from './types';
import { Check } from 'lucide-react';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const ORDERS_FILE = "orders.json";

export function saveOrder(order2: OrderType): void {
  let orders: OrderType[] = [];
  
  const data = fs.readFileSync(ORDERS_FILE, 'utf8');
  orders = JSON.parse(data);
  orders.push(order2);

  fs.writeFileSync(ORDERS_FILE, JSON.stringify(orders, null, 2));
}

type OrderConfirmationProps = {
  order: OrderType;
  onClose: () => void;
};

export function OrderConfirmation({ order, onClose }: OrderConfirmationProps) {
  saveOrder(order);
  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black/50 flex items-center justify-center p-4">
      <div className="bg-white rounded-lg p-6 max-w-md w-full">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center mb-6">
          <div className="bg-green-100 rounded-full p-2">
            <Check className="w-8 h-8 text-green-600" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-center mb-4">Order Confirmed!</h3>
        <p className="text-center mb-4">Your order ID is: <br />
          <span className="font-mono bg-gray-100 px-2 py-1 rounded">{order.id}</span>
        </p>
        <div className="border-t border-b py-4 my-4">
          <h4 className="font-semibold mb-2">Order Summary:</h4>
          {order.items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id} className="flex justify-between text-sm">
              <span>{item.quantity}x {item.name}</span>
              <span>${(parseFloat(item.price) * item.quantity).toFixed(2)}</span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-between font-semibold mb-6">
          <span>Total:</span>
          <span>${order.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</span>
        </div>
        <button
          onClick={onClose}
          className="w-full bg-amber-700 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-amber-800 transition-colors"
        >
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

it was all working untill i added saveOrder() function.
it shows me this error on console:
Uncaught Error: Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "fs.readFileSync" in client code.  See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.

I was trying to fix this, but to be honest, i have no idea how paths work.

This is running in the customers' browsers. It's certainly not going to be able to write to a local file, much less one on the server.

The answer depends on what you actually want saveOrder to do. Do you want to save it on the user's computer as a normal file? See eg. this question. Do you just want to store the file somewhere on the user's browser for later use? Look up localstorage. Do you want to save the file on the server for long term storage or for multiple users? You'll need a server and a separate service running on it for that.

The fs (file system) module is a Node.js module and is not available in the browser environment. You need to store in a local storage or any back end service
import React from 'react';
import { OrderType } from './types';
import { Check } from 'lucide-react';

const ORDERS_KEY = "orders";

export function saveOrder(order2: OrderType): void {
  // Get the existing orders from localStorage (if any)
  const storedOrders = localStorage.getItem(ORDERS_KEY);
  let orders: OrderType[] = storedOrders ? JSON.parse(storedOrders) : [];

  // Add the new order to the array
  orders.push(order2);

  // Save the updated orders array back to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem(ORDERS_KEY, JSON.stringify(orders));
}

type OrderConfirmationProps = {
  order: OrderType;
  onClose: () => void;
};

export function OrderConfirmation({ order, onClose }: OrderConfirmationProps) {
  // Save the order to localStorage
  saveOrder(order);

  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black/50 flex items-center justify-center p-4">
      <div className="bg-white rounded-lg p-6 max-w-md w-full">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center mb-6">
          <div className="bg-green-100 rounded-full p-2">
            <Check className="w-8 h-8 text-green-600" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-center mb-4">Order Confirmed!</h3>
        <p className="text-center mb-4">Your order ID is: <br />
          <span className="font-mono bg-gray-100 px-2 py-1 rounded">{order.id}</span>
        </p>
        <div className="border-t border-b py-4 my-4">
          <h4 className="font-semibold mb-2">Order Summary:</h4>
          {order.items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id} className="flex justify-between text-sm">
              <span>{item.quantity}x {item.name}</span>
              <span>${(parseFloat(item.price) * item.quantity).toFixed(2)}</span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-between font-semibold mb-6">
          <span>Total:</span>
          <span>${order.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</span>
        </div>
        <button
          onClick={onClose}
          className="w-full bg-amber-700 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-amber-800 transition-colors"
        >
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


